# What happens if I override window.scrollTo method?

Tags: javascript, scrollto

I am new to javascript programming, so please bear with me for a basic question :)
If accidentally one of the open source javascript code modifies the native window.scrollTo() method, how can I ensure that when calling scrollTo for a HTML element, it will always work, and not raise an JS error instead?

Comment: i think you should try it first

Comment: yes I did try, a JS error was raised. So don't know how can I always ensure that the default window's method should be called always :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore the default version of `scrollTo` by simply deleting the modification.

```
delete window.scrollTo;
```

This will remove the modified `window.scrollTo` and replace it with the default version of the function from the Window object prototype.

However, if you need the modified version of `window.scrollTo` you can make a copy of it and use the copy.

Execute the following code BEFORE you load the library:

```
window.scrollToProper = window.scrollTo;
```

From then on you can call `scrollToProper()` to use the default function, even if `window.scrollTo` gets modified.

Alternatively, you can call the default `scrollTo` function directly from the Window prototype. (Thanks rishabh.) The syntax is as follows:

```
Window.prototype.scrollTo.call(window, x, y);
```

Note the capitalization of Window, because you are referring to the Window object rather than the current instance.

Comment: Makes sense. though one more solution, not sure if this is correct, but please do let me know what are the potential hazarads in calling the same: ````Window.prototype.scrollTo.call(window, someParam);````

Comment: Thanks, @rishabh, that works as well. However I updated my answer with an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `delete window.scrollTo;` didn't help me. It really deleted the method and after the deletion `window.scrollTo` was `undefined`.

So I managed to deal with it by saving initial method to a variable and restore it when I needed:

```
const initialScrollMethod = window.scrollTo;

// replacing the original method
Object.defineProperty(window, 'scrollTo', {
  value: (option: ScrollToOptions) => {
    ...
  },
});

// restoring when I need it
Object.defineProperty(window, 'scrollTo', {
  value: initialScrollMethod,
});
```

If someone wondering when exactly is the right time to restore the method, I did it in Vue's `onUnmounted` clause.